# How to download the latest pre-release of Manjaro Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, manjaro, download, amd

From [DistroWatch](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=manjaro), I can see there is a version of Manjaro marked as "stable" which is more recent than the last release, 18.0.4. However I cannot find any link to download it, not even on Manjaro website.

I know that being a rolling release I could install 18.0.4 (kernel 4.19) and then upgrade, but my laptop (AMD Ryzen 2700U) does not support kernel versions older than 5.0.

Is it possible to get a pre-built version of the latest development Manjaro Linux?

Comment: https://osdn.net/projects/manjaro/

Comment: Thank you. If you put it as an answer, I will approve it.

Answer (score 0):

Go here, you can download the release clients. https://osdn.net/projects/manjaro-community/storage/

Comment: Hi Bill. Welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: I just tried to install the RC5 version on Manjaro, and even this one does not work on my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPard E585, Ryzen 2700U). Tried Fedora, and it does not work either...